# Why are threads slowing down the execution of my program?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have some code that can make use of parallelism for efficiency gain. Since my PC has a dual processor I tried running the code on two threads. So I wrote the below code (This is a very simplified version of it):

```
Evaluator::evaluate(vector<inpType> input, bool parallel) {
    std::thread t0;
    if(parallel) {
        // Evaluate half of the input in a spawned thread
        t0 = std::thread(&Evaluator::evaluatePart, this, std::ref(input), 0, input.size()/2 + input.size()%2);
        // Evaluate the other half of the input in this thread
        evaluatePart(input, input.size()/2 + input.size()%2 - 1, input.size()/2);
    } else {
        // sequential evaluate all of the input
        evaluatePart(input, 0, input.size());
    }
    // some other code

    // after finishing everything join the thread
    if(parallel) t0.join();
}

Evaluator::evaluatePart(vector<inpType> &input, int start, int count) {
    for(int i=start; i<count; i++) {
        evaluateSingle(input[i]);
    }
}

Evaluator::evaluateSingle(inpType &input) {
    // do stuff with input
    // note I use a vector<int> belonging to Evaluator object in here, not sure it matters though
}
```

Running sequentially takes around 3 ms but running in parallel is taking around 6 ms. Does that mean spawning a thread takes so much time that it is more efficient to just evaluate sequentially? Or am I doing something wrong?

Note that I don't make use of any locking mechanisms because the evaluations are independent on each other. Every evaluateSingle reads from a vector that is a member of the Evaluator object but only alters the single input that was given to it. Hence there is no need for any locking.

**Update**

I apologize that I didn't make this clear. This is more of a pseudo code describing in abstract how my code looks like. It will not work or compile but mine does so that is not the issue. Anyways I fixed the t0 scope issue in this code.

Also the input size is around 38,000 which I think is sufficient enough to make use of parallelism.

**Update**

I tried increasing the size of input to 5,000,000 but that didn't help. Sequential is still faster than multi-threaded.

**Update**

I tried increasing the number of threads running while splitting the vector evenly between them for evaluation, and got some interesting results:

[image]

Note that I have an [i7-7500U](https://ark.intel.com/products/95451/Intel-Core-i7-7500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz-) CPU that can run 4 threads in parallel. This leaves me with two questions:

1. Why does creating 4 or more threads starts to see a performance improvement in comparison with 2, 3.
2. Why is it the case that creating more than 4 threads is more efficient than 
   just 4 threads (the maximum the CPU can run concurrently).

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the problem. It's critical for us to see what, if anything, is being modified.

Comment: You never wait for `t0` to finish processing. Also `if(parallel) t0.join();` part won't work because `t0` scope is inside of `if(parallel)` block.

Comment: Threads are not silver bullets. You have to learn to use them to gain performance.

Comment: There will obviously be a point at which the *vector* you are processing is too small to benefit from multiple threads because the overhead of creating the threads will be large in comparison to the amount of work needing  to be done. It may be worth testing with larger vectors to see if that may be the case here?

Comment: Try to increase input size (like 100x). If parallel version becomes faster with a larger input, then yes, thread spawn and join takes that much time.

Comment: @Robert: it is executed parallel. But you're right on the part that this code is not even compilable in the first place.

Comment: @geza you are right... missed that part ^^... comment deleted

Comment: Depending on what your type is and what you do with it `38,000` may be insignificant. In my tests using your code (and incrementing integers) the "break-even" point where using threads becomes faster than not is at about `900,000` elements. And a clear winner doesn't emerge until about `1.2M` elements

Comment: @Galik Thanks for the input. Interesting point, I though 38,000 would be large enough to make multi-threading worth while but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @user1546022 please check the updated answer.